# Scala/Play error Overloaded method value [tuple] cannot be applied to

Tags: scala, playframework

Scala/Play error @Overloaded method value [tuple] cannot be applied to:
Please see below code

```
def getPropertyFromRequest(implicit request: Request[AnyContent]): (Property, Option[ObjectId], Option[ObjectId], Option[ObjectId]) = {
    val p =
      Form(tuple(
        "desc" -> text,
        "url" -> text,
        "image" -> text,
        "price" -> text,
        "sqft" -> text,
        "address2" -> text,
        "lotsize" -> text,
        "taxes" -> text,
        "status" -> optional(text),
        "maint" -> text,
        "address" -> text,
        "mls" -> text,
        "baths" -> text,
        "beds" -> text,
        "partial_baths" -> text,
        "propertyId" -> optional(text),
        "snoopId" -> optional(text),
        "year_built" -> text,
        "groupId" -> optional(text) //upon adding this, error show up
      )).bindFromRequest().fold(
          errors => {Logger.error(errors.toString())
            throw new Error("could not parse form")},
          success => success
      )

      val a = GeoCoder.create(p._11 + " " + p._6)
      val property = Property(url = p._2,
        description = p._1,
        image = p._3,
        price = parseAmount(p._4).toDouble,
        sqft = p._5,
        lotSize = p._7,
        taxes = parseAmount(p._8),
        status = PropertyStatus.ACTIVE,
        maintenance = parseAmount(p._10),
        mls = p._12,
        baths = try{p._13.toDouble}catch{case e => 0},
        beds = try{p._14.toInt}catch{case e=> 0},
        partialBaths = try{p._15.toInt}catch{case e => 0},
        address = a,
        yearBuilt = Some(p._18))

      ( property, p._16.map(new ObjectId(_)) ,p._17.map(new ObjectId(_)), p._19.map(new ObjectId(_)) )
  }
```

Note:
This code is working correctly but upon adding **groupID** on tuple list, error show up.
according to my research tuple is up 22max element only, but this one is up to 19 counts, so not sure whats happening.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

The `tuple` method in [`Forms`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.data.Forms%24) is only overloaded for up to 18-tuple.

I don't know why Play stops at 18, it seems as arbitary as 22.

There are a couple of work arounds. Either write your own `tuple` methods for the larger arity tuples, or use nested mappers.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, In this case, what is the best thing I should do?

Comment: might help others.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/2Vi7DAmMQA8 

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/SVrcyC2Dtdo